# some issues with index range, python student project?

Tags: python-3.x, range, index-error

```
def f3():

    root.withdraw()
    viewest.deiconify()
    #import cx_Oracle
    con=None
    cursor=None
    try:
        con=cx_Oracle.connect("system/abc123")
        cursor=con.cursor()
        sql="select * from students"
        cursor.execute(sql) 
        msg=""
        for d in data:
            msg=msg+" R: "+ str(d[0]) + " N: " + str(d[1])+" M: " + str(d[2])+ "\n"
            stData.insert(INSERT,msg)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        print("some issues",e)

    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor.close()
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
            print("Disconnected")
```

'''IndexError: string index out of range , msg=msg+" R: "+ str(d[0]) + " N: " + str(d[1])+" M: " + str(d[2])+ "\n" '''

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverFlow! We will try to answer your questions but some tips in general -  it would be more helpful for all of us to see what you've done/tried so far, what your issue is (described), and any errors you might be getting as it adds more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you're trying to do here but what's the data type of `data`? It looks like you're not getting past the `try` statement (good use of a try/except to handle Exceptions!) so the issue I think lies in the way you're indexing the items (`d`) in `data`. Think about it: if `data` didn't exist (meaning you didn't initialize it in your code for your program to use), how can you try to index it later on? Also, it's weird that you're not getting a `NameError` as I don't see `data` defined anywhere unless you cropped out where it was defined earlier (unless my eyes are tricking me).

**General Programming principles:**

- Iterable Objects: `String`, `List`, `Dictionary`, etc...
- Non-iterable Objects: `Integer`, `Float`, `Boolean`, etc... (depending on programming language)

Iterable data types are ones that you can index using bracket notation (`[]`) so in any case, you'll need to know the types of your variables and then use the correct "processes" to work with them. Since you are indexing items in `data`, the data type of `data` therefore, needs to be an iterable too.

In general, an `IndexError` means that you've tried to access/index an item in a list for example but that item didn't exist. Therefore, I think that trying to string AND index an item in an object that doesn't exist is giving you that error.

**Here's what I think would help:**

If I could see where you have `data` defined, I would be able to tell you where you may be going wrong, but for now, I can only recommend you going back to see whether you've indexed an item in `d` in `data` that doesn't exist.

An example (I will assume `data` is a list for clarity):

```
>>> data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> data[0] # index a list in d in data
[1, 2, 3]
>>> data[0][1]
2

# If you try to access an index in data that doesn't exist:
>>> data[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I probably over-explained by now, so I'll just end this here. The above implementation was to give you an idea of how to access a list in a list correctly and when it isn't properly done what can happen. Hope this is clear!